# FTPClient.rename(from,to) function return false

Tags: java, android, apache-commons, ftp-client

i am developing an android application and willing to rename the file over FTP Server but getting false in return please help whats wrong with code. Code is as follows

```
public boolean Rename(final FTPFile remoteFile, final String path, final String renameToo) throws IOException {
    Log.e("Rename","Renaming file 1");
   new AsyncTask<String,String,String>(){
       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
           Log.e("Rename","Renaming file 2");
    client=new FTPClient();
    try {

        client.connect(host,port);
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        if(client.getReplyCode()>-1){

            boolean loginStatus=client.login(user,password);
            if(loginStatus){

                status=client.rename(path+"/"+remoteFile.getName(),renameToo);//always false ?

                Log.e("Rename Status", String.valueOf(status)); 
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error", String.valueOf(e));
        status=false;
    }
    finally {
        if(client.isConnected()){
            try {
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
           return null;
       }
   }.execute();
    return status;
}
```

Comment: You should tell the value of your parameters and paths as we dont know what you are doing

Comment: Further it is strange that you use a FtpFile instance but yet have to connect.

Comment: everything else working just fine mean connection etc is ok just getting error  from this line      clien.login(filenamefrom,filenameto); this line always returns false

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure that your FTP user has permissions to change files in this directory.

2.Make sure that your FTP server has permissions from operation system to make changes in its home directory and subdirectories.

I've got the same problem with FTP Server (FileZilla) running on Windows. I could download files, but I couldn't rename them or move to the subdirectory. After some research I realized that home directory of my FTP server was read-only.

Try to get FTP response code in debugger. In my case, it was 550 (Requested action not taken. File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).)

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes